# Export an APK library project, and use it in another Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

Today my **final** project setup has an Android library dependency. That Android library dependency project is located in the same workspace as the **final** project.

I would like to **export** that library project with its **SOURCES and ANDROID RESOURCES**, into some **archive**, jar, apk, apklib, anything that would allow me to add that file as a dependency, and not be forced to include/checkout a project with its **sources and resources** into the workspace.

I know Maven kinda solve this, but that is not my goal, I'm trying to allow simple Eclipse Android project to be able to add the Android library as a dependency.

(I don't mind using the apklib Maven produces with a non Maven Android project in Eclipse, but I guess that would be meaningless...)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys,

As far as I've investigated, there is no way to do that.
I have to find a solution for this, or my [Cyborg](http://cyborg-framework.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/what-is-cyborg.html) distribution would be hell.

I would have to write a script that would do that for me...

If something has changed, and ADT would decide to grow some sense, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a "regular" Java project and import from there
>   Android.jar. Then, you will have access to every component in the SDK.
>   Then, you can export your project as jar... and load it from your
>   Android app. This works great and it seems a preety straightforward
>   way to do it.

[Create an Android Jar library for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014128/create-an-android-jar-library-for-distribution)

Comment: @TacB0sS You **can** have resources in the library. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17064024/636571) out.

Comment: @TacB0sS Did you find a solution to export your lib with resources?

Comment: Unfortunately not...  There is a trick however to split your project into two, one only resources, the other only the code. the first you supply fully, with the resources, and the other as a Jar. it seems to work, Google uses it to distribute their libraries, for example play-store api, but unless you have a continues integration this is a hassle to manage!