# Proguard can't find referenced class when run from command line

Tags: adt, proguard

I have a library project that processes very well through [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html) when exported in Eclipse as part of the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) tool chain.

But now I would like to manually run Proguard directly on the library jar as outlined in the step #3 [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064024/2597758).

So after copying the library jar to the `libs/` folder, I ran:

```
java -jar C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar @../bin/proguard.txt  -verbose -injar mylibproj.jar
```

And what I get in return is about zillion (more or less) warning messages like this:

```
Warning: com.unilj.mylib.FancyDialog: can't find referenced class java.lang.String
```

Why am I receiving this (what am I doing wrong?) and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the command you ran, looks like you are missing the important piece of `-libraryjars`, e.g.

```
-libraryjars c:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar
```

If you are using additional libraries, you may want to include them as well. To find out which libraries you are using, go back to Eclipse > Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and check **Android Dependencies**.

Also, don't forget to reference your `*.java` (most notably `R.java`) in your bin/classes:

```
-injars ../bin/classes
```

For more information, look at the [Troubleshooting section](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) of the ProGuard Manual

Comment: Updated link for "Troubleshooting Section" - http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html