# What Should my utility class extend?

Tags: android, class, utility

Hi i am creating an external jar file and that is a library for reshaping a text view and here is the reshape class :

```
public class Reshaper extends Activity{
    public static Context co;

    public static void ReshapeTextview(TextView Textview, String fontpath) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(co.getAssets(), fontpath);
        Textview.setTypeface(tf);
        PersianReshape.reshape(Textview.getText().toString());
    }
```

and here is how i use it in other project that i have imported that jar there.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Reshaper.ReshapeTextview(tv, "title.TTF");

    }
```

but when i launch it i got a force close !

and here is the log:

```
11-29 19:13:48.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1218): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mr.persian.reshape.Reshaper
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at com.example.mm.Main.onCreate(Main.java:15)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-29 19:13:48.678: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Reshaper doesn't need Activity's behaviour. So do not extend anything. You have other kind of problem: VM cant find Reshaper class.

Comment: @Leonidos  I have followed this tutorial to export a jar file! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project

Comment: You missed something and your jar is not in your apk or it's in wrong place )

Answer (score 0):

Don't have it extend anything and accept a `Context` as a parameter in your static methods.

You can probably do something like:

```
public class Reshaper {
    public static void ReshapeTextview(TextView Textview, String fontpath) {
        Context co = Textview.getContext();
        ReshapeTextview(Textview, fontpath, co);
    }

    // If the Context returned is not the correct one, you can accept a context as a parameter:
    public static void ReshapeTextview(TextView Textview, String fontpath, Context co) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(co.getAssets(), fontpath);
        Textview.setTypeface(tf);
        PersianReshape.reshape(Textview.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

In terms of the error you are seeing, the comments are correct in that the class `Reshaper` is not found, which implies it's not in the classpath.

Comment: may you explain your answer a bit?