# Archiving classes into non-accessible packages

Tags: android, archive

hello I've an android application created in Eclipse ,
 i want to convert the solution into archive so no one can use this code if i give it to him.
I've searched Google on how to do such thing , but I've found nothing

is there a way to do this ??!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your source code to a jar and use it in your Android Project.
Check this post [How to create jar for Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project)

Step #1: Create a regular Android library project, and get it working.

Step #2: Copy that Android library project into another directory.

Step #3: Create a JAR from the compiled Java classes from the original Android library project, and put that JAR in the libs/ directory of the copy you made in Step #2. You should be able to run ProGuard on this JAR manually, though I haven't tried that.

Step #4: Remove everything inside the src/ directory of the copied library project, leaving behind and empty src/ directory.

Step #5: ZIP up or otherwise distribute the copied Android library project.

This will give you an Android library project like the Play Services one, where the resources are available, but the source code is not.