# how to call android framework function in module project

Tags: android, sdk

I build a module in android studio, but in the module, the class of it, I cannot call any android functions. like "Log.d"、"Context".

How can I use the function of android framework in a module project.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is hard to tell, but I think you are not extending the class `Activity` in any of your classes

Update:

see this answer to see how to create a library project:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064024/1173391

Here is a step by step instruction on how to do this:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: yes, that's true. But I do not need any layout in my sdk. Just want to use some functions of framework. Like Context, Handler and so on.

Comment: yeah therefore you need to extend from any Activity class

Comment: and this means I should build an android project, add AndroidManifest.xml. And if I do like this, I cannot get a .jar any more

Comment: of course you can, it is just a normal library project

Comment: can you tell me how to do that. I just cannot find in build/libs a jar. I use the way post at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project

Comment: I cannot find "jar" option of gradle, If I add AndroidManifest.xml in my module.

Comment: follow the tutorial link from above

Comment: but u know, I just followed it. And it's going well, when I do not use any android framework functions. But If I add some android functions, jar option of gradle will be gone.

Comment: how can I get framework functionality. I just import android.jar to the module. But it doesn't work.