# How to add module dependencies in an Android library .jar using Android Studio and gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have an Android Library project in which I'm having module dependencies. Now I want to export this Library Project as a .jar. How can I export it as a .jar which includes the module dependencies also?

Comment: does your project include resource files (e.g. drawables) ?

Comment: This question has already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project)

Comment: May be an aar or a maven module with a pom file is a better solution

Comment: Please clarify if you *specifically* need a jar with just the classes from the project and all its dependencies, or if the more commonly-used aar format (which can include Android resources) is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add module dependencies in an Android library .jar using Android Studio and gradle, you can do it in three different ways. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.