# How make a Jar file of project with layout and drawable dependency?

Tags: android, jar, executable-jar

I have a project of which I want to make jar file. But this project needs some layout and some drawable.

If i will export jar file of source code how will i give support of layout and drawable in other projects where i will that jar as lib.

Please help with the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an apklib.

I'm not sure if there is a way to bundle them up yourself [unless you are using maven](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib).

If you are using eclipse you can right click the project->properties->android and check "is library". Now you will be able to include that project as a dependency in other Android projects in your workspace :project->properties->android->add (in the library section at the bottom).

Comment: What if i want to export it and then add it to library then ?

Comment: I use the android maven plugin for common code/resources. It seems there are some other methods (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014128/create-an-android-jar-library-for-distribution) however I cannot comment on how well they work.

Comment: Thanks bro i would take a loot in to it