# unable to refer library project android on updated adt

Tags: java, android, adt

I want to integrate facebook library project to my project ...

Steps i followed:

1.Imported facebook library project

2.Checked it as isLibrary

---

1.Imported facebook sample project

3.Added library project -facebook

**Pls help to solve the problem depicted in the screenshot...**

[image]

**Edit**:Problem is in ADT 20.3 .... i tried same steps in ADT 10.3 and it works fine(Just one change here instead of importing the project i created "new project from existing source" );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to build your library project, and only after that add  it into main project as library.

Comment: You are right .. i was unchecked build automaticlly before... so that was the problem thakns