# R.java in dependency project incomplete after update

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have an android project B that uses a library project A.
Since I installed API17 using Android SDK manager (12 Dec 2012) and did a Check for Updates inside Eclipse which downloaded the most recent versions of the android addins the auto generated R.Java file for the dependent project B no longer contains R.xxx.identifiers for id's defined in project B. For example: R.layout's added to project B can not longer be found in source: undefined ident error, R.id's defined in those layouts can not be found. I have done a "Clean Project" and restarted Eclipse several times all to no avail.
Any ideas?

Which addin auto generates the R.java files and is there a way to revert to a previous version of this tool?

Comment: Did you try cleaning for all projects?

Comment: Yes, obviously. Several times.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970802/unable-to-refer-library-project-android-on-updated-adt/13259971#13259971).

Comment: That does not help. I used to build OK for months. Only after updating the project no longer builds. I have temp disabled "auto build" and did a manual build for each project in order of dependency. Does not make a difference.