# Android library project within an Android library project that needs string resource id

Tags: android, android-resources

I have my own Android library project (e.g. libA). In its libs/ folder, it uses another 3rd party Android library B.jar which has res/strings in it that it uses for itself. In my final Android application project "C", it includes libA. When the code from B.jar runs and attempts to reference a string it supplied for itself, the resource id comes out to be 0. Now, libA also has res/strings, and it can access them fine. I can see the aapt -S command reference the directory of my Android library project libA. So the question is how to get aapt to compile in the resources from the 3rd party .jar file which is being used by my Android library project?

Its like the Russian nesting dolls! :)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970802/unable-to-refer-library-project-android-on-updated-adt/13259971#13259971) answer. Or create one library project with same resources from 3 projects.