# How to create a distribution jar for an Android Library with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have developed an Android Library (without resources) and I want to release it as a jar. For standard Android applications I use to "export" them but for Android Library it doesn't work.
Is there a standard way to create a distribution jar for those libraries within Eclipse?
In case of a positive answer can I use Proguard to obfuscate them?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014128/create-an-android-jar-library-for-distribution?rq=1

Comment: its automatically generated by eclipse ADT.

Comment: Is there a way to obfuscate them?