# How to convert android library project into jar?

Tags: android, jar

I had created an android library project.Now I am looking to distribute my library project  as a jar to the 3rd party for the security of my code. I had searched a lot about how to convert a library project to a jar.But I didn't get the proper solution.So is it possible to convert any library project to jar ?? How can I convert my library to jar ??? please help me with steps , thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an Android Jar library for distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014128/create-an-android-jar-library-for-distribution)

Comment: interesting that you think a jar is more secure... it's basically just a zip containing the .class files - and it's fairly easy to decompile those.

Comment: you can export your library project as jar.

Comment: if, the library contains attrs and layouts then in that case it is not appropriate to convert it to a jar. i have tried it myself and the problem is the layout or view(code custom view) will not be available and hence it would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse select your library project

1:right click on project 
2: select export
3:java then jar

Select all files, except the AndroidManifest.xml.

Make sure you DON'T select manifest file. Else it will lead to conflict errors.

Now include this JAR file in the build path, and it will work. I did the same.

Let me know if you have any issues.
[image]

Comment: First, **never manually mess with the Eclipse build path**. The proper place for JARs is in `libs/`. Second, your recipe will only work if the Android library project does not contain resources.

Comment: as you said I export my jar and integrated it to another project.When I run the second project it shows error " Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher5.png "

Comment: i show in image. i make jar library from android project library.

Comment: I used resources like layout and xml file in my project.So is it cause error??