# How to add EasyPost Library to Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, easypost

I have downloaded the library which is a folder containing several files from: 
https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-java/archive/master.zip

I have added my own folder named myLibs and added the unzipped project folder to it (folder named easypost-java-master).

My settings.gradle looks as follows:

```
include ':app'
include ':myLibs:easypost-java-master'
```

My build.gradle looks as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'myLibs', include: ['easypost-java-master'])
}
```

I am getting no errors and able to sync. But when I try to import for example `import com.easypost.EasyPost;`at my MainActivity, I get the error

**Cannot resolve easypost**

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing a step?

Yes, the  BIG one. On EasyPost library GitHub profile, there are installation instructions. Did you notice that:

> #### Installation
>
> `mvn package` or build the jar from src!

To do it, just follow these steps:

> In the latest build of Android Studio 1.2, the creation of JAR library
>   has been made as simple as point and click.
>
> Steps to follow :
>
> - Goto File -> New -> New Module [image]
> - Select "Java Library" at the end of the options list [image]
> - Enter the name of the jar lib and name of class in it and hit finish button [image]
> - Thats it !
>
> The next step is adding your Jar Library as dependency in your app.
>   Simple as that just
>
> - Goto File -> Project Structure -> Select 'app' -> Select 'Dependency'
> - Select the '+' at the bottom -> Select 'Module Dependency' [image]
> - Select your jar lib module you just created above [image] [image]
> - Select Ok and thats it!
>
> ....Or you could just add the below line to your App gradle file
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // Default Gradle Task, should be already present
>       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' // Default Gradle Task, should be already present
>
>       compile project(':nameOfYourJarLibraryModule') // This is your jar library module
>  }
> ```
>
> Google is promoting the Android Archive(AAR), even though JAR
>   supported is brought back to android studio.To find out the difference
>   between AAR and JAR refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar)
>
> From: [Create an Android Jar library for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014128/create-an-android-jar-library-for-distribution)

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't get it. I have created the dependency and added the jar file as you shown. Where does the project easypost-java-master come into place in this picture? I thought maybe the newly created class should contain the code snipper shown on the Github page but I am not able to import com.easypost.EasyPost still.

Comment: well, I haven't done it yest. You must create a .JAR file, then add it to `libs` folder in your project directory. Then you need to add to `build.gradle` file.... Here's a link how to do the next step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: Only two steps: generate JAR from source and add JAR to Android project

Comment: Probably sounding silly but I want to clarify. How do I generate this Jar from source? At the end all I will have is one single jar file? Regarding the link I belive you mean to follow the selected answer?

Comment: well I thought that this link would help you :-/ ask an author on Github project profile by new issue ;-0